# Undo view Google Photos in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

When I went to my photos in Google Drive, a popup appeared asking if I want to be able to [view my photos in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6156103?p=create_photos_folder&rd=2). I selected "Yes". How do I reverse this change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings, then on the "General" tab, uncheck "Automatically put your Google Photos into a folder in My Drive".

[image: Google Drive settings]

Comment: It may take some time to "take". I guess that depends on how many photos you have.

Comment: Unchecking this button has zero effect other than new photos are not added to the folder. From what others have reported, if you uncheck this box, then delete the folder, and finally empty trash...is it deletes all your photos.

Basically this is an irreversible action currently. Here is a link with a bunch of angry people:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/g433ImHfKBg